# Detecting state of application resume from different navigation state android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to record state of application when it is resumed/created from different point of entry.

- app is opened from app drawer
- app is opened from notification
- app is opened from open apps (Long home press)
- app is resumed from other screen

I know it can be traced by generating a base activity and overriding resume/pause events, but I have bulk of activity present in app. so is there any short method to get the state of application?

---

I thought about creating a service and continuously checking current running tasks, but I can only use this approach if I found a way to run the service only when my activity is in visible state. (for that to bind service in each activity is not practical for me)

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested solution sounds good to me:

```
public class YourBaseActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(1);

        tasks.get(0).topActivity.getClassName();

        //Do what you need to do with it...
    }
}
```

And let all your activities extends this one instead of Activity should work for you

---

**EDIT**
Another way to do it:

Create your own application class and implement Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks, a working example of the code:

```
public class ApplicationTest extends Application implements   Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
        Log.d("testing", "onActivityResumed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {
    }
}
```

And reference this class in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:name="com.example.testing.ApplicationTest" >
```

Comment: Guillermo, my friend that's what we actually know, we don't want to do that please provide other solutions than that. This is not acceptable.

Comment: Hi @MKJParekh I've edited my answer with an alternative solution, please check it

Comment: Are the callbacks being called when we navigate inside the app ? If I start an activity, will I get onActivityPaused and onActivityResumed for the other one ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis yes, I've tested with 2 activities and it works

Comment: What does it mean ? Is the paused and resumed callnacks called for all activity creation ? Or just when the app is paused/resumed ?

Comment: you have callbacks for creation/destroy and pause/resume, all of them are triggered correctly

Comment: @hanry have you found another solution for this?